# Ubuntu display mess

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display, connection, remote

hope someone can provide any hint about this.

for past weeks some of my ubuntu client pc's have been losing any kind of image on screen out of nowhere. i mean, the screen goes completely black and i'm unable to do anything remotely. i have to  force restart manually for any image to come back. i've been trying to restart the xorg or graphic server remotely (since they are several clients and are located in different sites) but i'm also unable to see the desktop or console. i've been trying to send custom commands using anydesk or teamviewer but nothing seems to work. it is very unhelpful to just dispatch any local technician to just restart every time. the ubuntu version is 18.04 on those clients, this because some of my software is uncompatible with 22.

Comment: Just a thought - if your software won’t work with 22.04 but you’re only having problems with 18.04, could you upgrade them to 20.04?

Comment: i wish, but some of the software is not compatible with 22 yet